# How do you determine how many pumps you need in a pipeline?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering, pipelines

I am working on a pipeline design scenario[image] and I am trying to determine how many pumps I need. In addition to this diagram, I'm given a flow rate range and an acceptable velocity to also determine the diameter of the pipeline, which I have (using a Turbulent Flow III approach). The part that I am stuck on is determining how many pumps I need. Any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Find the total pressure drop or losses and that tells you how many pumps you need. Consider where the pumps should be located...

Answer (score 1):

Find the flowrate and the variation in flow, check what kind of redundancy you will need. From this you can decide if you want one or more pumps in parallel per pumping station.

Then, as per solar mikes answer, find the total head loss and decide if you need an additional pumping station (or several) along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on mostly on length, elevation changes, viscosity. But when the input says "tailings" , I think you have bigger problems like settling of solids in the low spots. First you need to know what velocity you need to prevent settling . Also add cleaning pig entry and exits. Actually the first question is "do you know what you are pumping?" . And the first question,"Why do you think more pumping is needed?".  Frequently the best engineering answer to to use one larger pump ( minimum infrastructure). What type of pump is planned ? Maybe the type of pump should be optimized.

Comment: This q reminds me of a crude oil pipeline problem we were given as students, 2000km with max pressure, flow, etc and one had to work out how many pumping stations as if the pumping was all at one point it exceeded the max pressure capacity of the pipe so the pumps need to be spaced along the pipeline.